# NodeJS Restify Nested Promise Error Handling

Tags: express, restify

I have made API on restify for my product. I have installed `loggly` and `newrelic` for monitoring purposes.

Recently `newrelic` notified me that there was an error somewhere in my code.

```
app.get('/myroute', (req, res, next) => {
   let payload = { /*...*/ };

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     /* some code */
     return resolve();
   })
     .then(/* some promise */)
     .then(() => {
         /* some code */

         sendEmail({params}); // some error was thrown from one of the promise chain
                              // inside this function...

         return something;
     })
     .then(/* some promise */)
     .then(() => {
       res.send(something);
     })
     .catch(next);
});
```

The promise chain resolved perfectly fine and user gets proper response, because I didn't *return* the `sendEmail` function. And I don't want to, because I don't want the user to wait for the response for long.

```
function sendMail(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      /* some code */
      return resolve();
    })
      .then(() => {
        params.abc.replace('a', 'b'); // error thrown, cannot find replace of undefined.
        return something;
      });
}
```

`newrelic` caught the error, but `loggly` didn't. I already have restify's  `formatters` setup but it won't be enough as the request was successfully served and didn't fall into `.catch(next)`.

I don't want a solution to fix the `sendMail` function. I just want to log if there is a bug like this.

Is there anyway to catch and log this type of error without putting a `.catch()` to `sendMail` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. I was trying `process.on('uncaughtException')` to handled it.

But I came across `process.on('unhandledRejection')` which did the job!

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection